# Dynamically adding and removing widgets

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

I'd like to dynamically add and remove widgets in a wxHaskell application.

My problems are:

- the window is resizable, but when it's manually made larger, clicking the "more" button shows it quickly flashing back to the minimum size. Without the `windowReLayout` call the window doesn't change size at all.
- `windowRemoveChild` looks like what I want but it's not exported from WXCore, so I'm guessing that's not intended to be used at this layer (**Edit:** also I didn't find a way to use it without having the program crash because it tries to paint into a non-existing window, even when removing it from the layout first and then removing it from its parent). But I couldn't find an alternative. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992299/535522) suggests simply hiding the widget, but in my real app I'm using a complex custom widget I'd like to have garbage collected.
- the parent/child relation is already defined when creating the widgets, can I get around doing that again for the layout? For example, can I give the panel a layout that will apply `row 5` to all its children automatically, without having to rebuild the layout for every change? (If I just remove the children from the layout but don't delete them from their parent they will simply be positioned at the origin, is that controlled by a kind of default layout?)

Here is a minimal example showing how I'm currently adding widgets, and how I tried to remove them.

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.WX

main :: IO ()
main = start $ do
   count <- varCreate 100
   items <- varCreate []
   f <- frame []
   cont <- panel f []

   -- add a button
   more <- button f
      [ text := "more"
      , on command := do
            n <- varGet count
            varSet count (n + 1)
            new <- button cont
                     [ text := show n
                     , on command := print n ]
            is <- varGet items
            let is' = new : is
            varSet items is'
            set cont [ layout := row 5 (map widget is') ]
            windowReLayout f
      ]

   -- remove a button
   less <- button f
      [ text := "less"
      , on command := do
            is <- varGet items
            case is of
               i : is' -> do
                  -- windowRemoveChild f i   -- crash
                  set i [ visible := False ] -- leak
                  set cont [ layout := row 5 (map widget is') ]
                  varSet items is'
                  return ()
               _ -> return ()
      ]

   set f [ layout := margin 5
                   $ column 5 [ row 5 [ widget more
                                      , widget less ]
                              , widget cont ] ]
```